# How to resize an existing pbuffer surface in GLX/OpenGL?

Tags: c++, opengl, server-side-rendering, x11, glx

I am using GLX pbuffer surface to render OpenGL applications in Linux. Here is a sample:

```c
GLOffscreenBuffer::GLOffscreenBuffer(unsigned width, unsigned height)
    : m_width(width)
    , m_height(height)
    , m_display(XOpenDisplay(0))
    , m_pbuffer(0)
    , m_context(0)
{
    if (!m_display) {
        std::cerr << "Error: XOpenDisplay()\n";
        return;
    }

    static const int configAttributes[] = {
        GLX_DRAWABLE_TYPE, GLX_PBUFFER_BIT,
        GLX_RENDER_TYPE, GLX_RGBA_BIT,
        GLX_RED_SIZE, 8,
        GLX_GREEN_SIZE, 8,
        GLX_BLUE_SIZE, 8,
        GLX_ALPHA_SIZE, 8,
        GLX_DOUBLEBUFFER, GL_FALSE,
        0
    };
    int configCount;
    GLXFBConfig* config = glXChooseFBConfig(m_display, 0, configAttributes, &configCount);
    if (!configCount) {
        std::cerr << "Error: glXChooseFBConfig()\n";
        XFree(config);
        XCloseDisplay(m_display);
        return;
    }

    static const int pbufferAttributes[] = {
        GLX_PBUFFER_WIDTH, static_cast<int>(width),
        GLX_PBUFFER_HEIGHT, static_cast<int>(height),
        0
    };
    m_pbuffer = glXCreatePbuffer(m_display, config[0], pbufferAttributes);
    if (!m_pbuffer) {
        std::cerr << "Error: glXCreatePbuffer()\n";
        XFree(config);
        XCloseDisplay(m_display);
        return;
    }

    m_context = glXCreateNewContext(m_display, config[0], GLX_RGBA_TYPE, 0, GL_TRUE);
    XFree(config);
    if (!m_context) {
        std::cerr << "Error: glXCreateNewContext()\n";
        glXDestroyPbuffer(m_display, m_pbuffer);
        XCloseDisplay(m_display);
        return;
    }
}
```

But I don't know how to resize this pbuffer surface when handling a X11 resizing event. It would be better if you can provide a demo.

Comment: What's the purpose of the PBuffer? Render to texture? If so you should use OpenGL framebuffer objects instead. Better performance, and cross platform. PBuffers are a *very old* method to implement off-screen surfaces, that goes back to the earliest days of OpenGL (ca. 1998)

Comment: @datenwolf I use pbuffer to do off-screen rendering in headless system.I seems that framebuffer objects is much better. I have not tried fbo, however, does it work with GLX in linux headless system? I remeber that `XOpenDisplay` fails when there is no `DISPLAY` enviornment variable. Like this question: [GLX offscreen rendering in headless system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75680223/glx-offscreen-rendering-in-headless-system). Even better if you know how to fix it.

Comment: For a long time now, you don't need GLX to create a GPU accelerated OpenGL. Nvidia has a nice tutorial on using EGL for creating headless OpenGL contexts without needing the help of an X server (also works while an X server is running): https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/egl-eye-opengl-visualization-without-x-server/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To put it simply, you can't resize a pbuffer. The only way is to destroy the old buffer and create a new one.

e.g.

```
//in order to receive configure events,
//StructureNotifyMask must be set in the event mask
//e.g. XSelectInput(dpy, win, StructureNotifyMask);

XEvent evt;
XNextEvent(dpy, &evt);

switch (evt.type) {

    case ConfigureNotify:

        if (m_pbuffer) {
            glXDestroyPbuffer(...);
        }

        //width : evt.xconfigure.width;
        //height: evt.xconfigure.height;
        m_pbuffer = glXCreatePbuffer(...);

    break;

}
```

**Note:** As **@datenwolf** pointed it out in the comments, render-to-texture is best done via Framebuffer objects.

Comment: Pretty sure is using PBuffer not to shoehorn doublebuffering, but for render-to-texture. Which should be done using FBOs anyway.

Comment: @datenwolf No idea why i've assumed the OP wants to do doublebuffering. Maybe the desire to sync the frame extents lead me to that conclusion. Nevertheless, i've edited my answer and left that (unnecessary) comment out.

Comment: @ErdalKüçük Thanks. It seems that can not resize GLX pbuffer dynamically. Is this suitable for EGL pbuffer? If so, I will try fbo to do off-screen rendering.

Comment: @ChenChen Yes, the same for fbos, textures, etc ... EGL is very similar to GLX and it is save to say that nowadays EGL has replaced GLX (no reason to prefer GLX over EGL, but plenty the other way around). Another reason to use fbos instead of pbuffers: fbo is OpenGL, no matter what the interface to the underlying window system is.